# My Indian visa expires in 35 days, My passport is Bangladeshi. How will I extend my Visa time?

Tags: visas, india, bangladesh

I took my Indian visa 27th Dec 2018, they gave me 3 months period which ends in 26th March which has literally 35 days left. How will I extend my visa period?

Comment: You haven't said what visa you have, but eVisas cannot be extended, and tourist visas can be extended while in India only in exceptional circumstances. If you have either of those you'll need to return to Bangladesh and apply from there.

Comment: And if you are working long term, maybe https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/ is more on topic than this site.

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify. Putting on hold for now.